# CakePHP hasAndBelogsToMany using save() vs. saveAll()

Tags: cakephp, entity-relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am using a very intrinsic database with a CakePHP application and so far my multi-models views and controllers are working fine. I have a singular table (`Entity`) that have it's `id` on several other tables as the Foreign Key `entity_id`

Some tables are one to one relations (Like a `Company` is one `Entity`) and some are one to many (`Entity` can have several `Addresses`) and so on.

*I won't/can't change the database model*, so this is the structure.

I have been using `saveAll()` to save data on those tables with input names like:

```
Entity.type='x' (hidden inside the view)
Company.name
Address.0.street
Address.0.city
Address.1.street
Address.1.city

... and so on ...
```

and my save all is doing all the hard job, `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, all `INSERT`s and a final `COMMIT` ...

But now I've created a `EntityCategory` that is a n to n  relation and created the full `HABTM` relation inside the model.

It works when I `save()` it but just the `HABTM` relation, and it saves everthing when I use `saveAll()` (just as before) except for the `HABTM` relation.

Am I missing something ? How I make this work correctly ? I am using the following code today:

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
  $this->Entity->saveAll($this->data);
  $this->Entity->save($this->data);
}
```

The `saveAll()` saves all data in several tables, saves the id in `Entity->id` and the `save()` saves the `HABTM` relations, but I am not sure if it is correct or if it can bring me problems if I change some structure/model.

Is this the best way to use it? Is there a *correct* way to save that relations inside CakePHP ? What your experience/knowledge can tell me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed if you download the [nightly](http://cakephp.org/downloads/index/nightly/1.2.x.x).

Be careful though, something else might break.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with saveAll() and HABTM associations is a known CakePHP [issue](https://trac.cakephp.org/ticket/4389), and has not been resolved as of 1.2 RC2.

As fas as best pratices for saving related model data goes, according to the CakePHP [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/75/Saving-Your-Data#Saving-Related-Model-Data-hasOne-hasMany-belongsTo-84):

> "When working with associated models, it is important to realize that saving model data should always be done by the corresponding CakePHP model. If you are saving a new Post and its associated Comments, then you would use both Post and Comment models during the save operation."

However, using saveAll() and save() should work, and IMHO is a more flexible/generic solution.